# How to solve InputMismatchException with Integer and char?

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I got this lines :

```
    while(flag==0){

    try{
        code=input.nextInt();
    }
    catch(java.util.InputMismatchException z)
    {
        System.out.print("\nDigito(s) Invalidos!\n");
        flag=1;
    }
    finally
    {
       if(flag==1)
       flag=0;
       else{flag=1;}

    }
}
```

But the `input.nextInt()` only works at the first time. What's the best way to prevent the user to insert a char on an Integer?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that bizarre `finally` block? Just use `break` instead of using `flag` at all.

Comment: `char` is a subset of `int`.  If you don't want your user to put bogus values in, then read them all in as a `String` instead and then parse out integer values from that.

Answer (score 1):

No need for flag or finally block in your case, you just can break the loop in  catch block, You can do the following :

```
        while(true){
            try{
                code=input.nextInt();
            }
            catch(java.util.InputMismatchException z)
            {
                System.out.print("\nDigito(s) Invalidos!\n");
                break;
            }
        }
```